# gcc -fno-stack-protector for linking not work

Tags: gcc, linker, stack-overflow, compiler-options

My gcc version : gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

the following is my makefile

```
all : main.o utility.o                                                                                                                                                                                       
    gcc -fno-stack-protector -Wl,-z,execstack -o binary main.o utility.o -lcrypto
main : main.c
    gcc -z execstack -fno-stack-protector main.c -c
utility: utility.c
    gcc  -z execstack -fno-stack-protector utility.c -c
```

The file utility.o and main.o does not have stack guard
But after linking there are some stack guard

```
objdump -D binary | grep chk
080488d0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>:
 8048e30:   e8 9b fa ff ff          call   80488d0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 80494dd:   e8 ee f3 ff ff          call   80488d0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 80498e2:   e8 e9 ef ff ff          call   80488d0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 8049b92:   e8 39 ed ff ff          call   80488d0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 8049c9e:   e8 2d ec ff ff          call   80488d0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 8049da2:   e8 29 eb ff ff          call   80488d0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 804a137:   e8 94 e7 ff ff          call   80488d0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
```

How to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

> the following is my makefile
>   `gcc -z execstack -fno-stack-protector main.c -c`

That command is bogus; if anything it should have `-Wl,-z,execstack`. However, since that's a linker option, and you are not linking here, best to remove `-z exestack` completely.

> But after linking there are some stack guard

The calls to `__stack_chk_fail` must be coming from some code linked into your binary. Perhaps from `libcrypto.a`, or from `libgcc.a`. You can *see* where they are coming from, in two ways:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -Wl,-z,execstack -o binary main.o utility.o \
 -lcrypto -Wl,-y,__stack_chk_fail
```

will produce messages like this:

```
/some/libfoo.a(bar.o): reference to __stack_chk_fail  # you care about this one!
/usr/lib/libc.so.6: definition of __stack_chk_fail
```

Or you can use the binary you already built:

```
objdump -d binary | egrep '>:$|__stack_chk_fail' | grep -B1 __stack_chk_fail
```

That should tell you which functions inside the binary reference `__stack_chk_fail`, and from that you should be able to guess where these functions are coming from.

P.S. Unless you are studying buffer overflow exploitation techniques, disabling stack protector and linking with `-z,execstack` is a *really bad idea*.

Comment: I would not call it “bogus”, it is an actual option and it is [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-z) that it is passed directly to the linker, so it does not need `-Wl`.